# Convert \n characters to newline in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can the `stdout` from calling `execFile` be formatted so that `\n` creates a new line in the output below, rather than simply printing the chracters `\n`?

**Code:**

```
execFile("node", childArgs, null, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log("execFileSTDOUT:", JSON.stringify(stdout));
})
```

**Current Output:**

```
execFileSTDOUT: "0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n50\n51\n52\n53\n54\n55\n56\n57\n58\n59\n60\n61\n62\n63\n64\n65\n66\n67\n68\n69\n70\n71\n72\n73\n74\n75\n76\n77\n78\n79\n80\n81\n82\n83\n84\n85\n86\n87\n88\n89\n90\n91\ndone\n"
```

**Desired Output:**

```
execFileSTDOUT: 
0
1
2
3
...
```

Comment: You're asking for it JSON encoded, which necessarily renders things as literal `\n`. Do you want it JSON or not? How about...not encoding it?

Comment: JSON doesn't allow literal new lines in strings, so if you were to get that output it wouldn't be JSON.

Comment: tadman's right, but to give you the answer, just do `console.log("execFileSTDOUT:\n", stdout);`

Answer (score -3, accepted):

use this   `"0\n1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10\n11\n12\n13\n14\n15\n16\n17\n18\n19\n20\n21\n22\n23\n24\n25\n26\n27\n28\n29\n30\n31\n32\n33\n34\n35\n36\n37\n38\n39\n40\n41\n42\n43\n44\n45\n46\n47\n48\n49\n50\n51\n52\n53\n54\n55\n56\n57\n58\n59\n60\n61\n62\n63\n64\n65\n66\n67\n68\n69\n70\n71\n72\n73\n74\n75\n76\n77\n78\n79\n80\n81\n82\n83\n84\n85\n86\n87\n88\n89\n90\n91\ndone\n".replace("\n","")`